# ToolbarItem is showing a spot instead of image?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm creating an app using Xamarin and I am trying to add a `ToolbarItem` with icon, on Android it works fine but on iOS it just show a white spot as can see in the image below and I don't know why it is happening.

How could I fix this ?

**ToolbarItem**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="icon.png"  />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar on iOS by default is showing only the colored alpha of the image. If you want to use the colored image you need to specify that the rendering mode of your asset is not default, but rather original.

Comment: How could I do that ?

Comment: Mostly as I have described above, you open the assets, select the image and then pick the proper option. It may vary whether you do it on Mac or PC